# Rails + Slim: Temple::InvalidExpression: Generator supports only core expressions - found [false, false, false]

Tags: ruby-on-rails, slim-lang

We started seeing this issue about month ago randomly on different servers with different environments (rails 4.0.12, 4.0.13 and rails 4.2). Some of requests throws that exception on random templates and if I repeat those falling requests several times with curl, with the same session, cookies – error doesn't present. Full backtrace here: [error backtrace](https://gist.github.com/gazay/f27860236dc8a11ec16d).

According to dates of first error all what we change – we added new asset compilation environment on node.js. But I don't see how it can affect slim templates (or temple if bug is there).

Our Gemfile is here: [gemfile](https://gist.github.com/gazay/c7884ec890448ceaeacf)

Do you have any idea what can trigger this kind of exception? I can provide other info if needed, but failing templates are totally random, even simple footer partial without any logic failed once.